# How offensive is ぷっくりする?

Tags: word-choice, words, adjectives

I've read the definition of ぷっくりする in a dictionary, and it can basically describe someone who is chubby. As I have rarely seen this expression used, I'd like to know how (in)appropiate it is. Is ぷっくり on the same level as デブ or 太っている?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I hear rarely ぷっくりしている but ぽっちゃりしている is commonly used as the meaning of chubby.

I think ぽっちゃりしている isn't offensive more than デブ and 太っている and it is the pretty way of saying of fatness.

However how the person feel the level as fatness is different with each person.

Comment: 「ぷっくり」is typically used for something more... not sure, spherical? Like [餅](http://www.irasutoya.com/2012/04/blog-post_1970.html), [blowfish](http://www.irasutoya.com/2012/12/blog-post_8023.html), lips, cheeks (human or [animals'](http://www.irasutoya.com/2015/01/blog-post_63.html)), buds, swallowing, etc. It usually has a nuance of having tension from inside, which might not really fit when used for an entire person.

Comment: @Yosh perhaps they visited willie wanka's chocolate factory.